# What's the precise effect of Inferno Propellant upgrade for the Galleon Mortar?

Tags: bastion

Well, everything's in the title.  [The description line](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Galleon_Mortar#Upgrades) seems a bit incomplete about that upgrade:

> Inferno Propellant (Bombs Create Damage Fields)

What's the exact effect of these damage fields ?

1. Any idea about the damage per second ?
2. Does it slow down enemies (the graphic representation of the effect looks a bit like a [Scumbags](http://bastion.wikia.com/wiki/Scumbag)'s goo) ?
3. Does it work with the Bomb Barrage secret skill (reminder: *"An experimental technique that overloads the firing tube with several shells that launch simultaneously"*) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The damage field hits enemies for 9-10 damage every 0.5 seconds or so while they remain in the area of effect, so the damage per second should be around 18-20. Choosing the High-Explosive Charges upgrade (+35% damage) also increases the damage of the field to 12-13, making the dps more like 24-26. Note: All of these damage values are for unarmoured enemies found in the first Who Knows Where area. I'm not sure if the damage field will damage armoured enemies.
2. The field does not appear to slow enemies down at all.
3. Yes, If you use the Bomb Barrage skill to fire multiple mortar rounds simultaneously, all of the rounds create a damage field.